# Trying out WHM/cPanel

Tags: cpanel, whm

I have a live site running on cPanel. I would like to write some WHM plugins to extend WHM functionality. But the problem I am facing is I don't seem to find a way to get cPanel as a developer version - which I can run on a development environment, test it and then install it to production.

Any idea anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a developer cPanel available, you could try having a test server/environment with cPanel installed, making the plugin etc and just testing live on that.

you could always open a support ticket with cPanel and see what the have to offer, they might have something which would work for you, but just isn't publicly displayed as such.